# Haskell read raw keyboard input

Tags: haskell, io, terminal

I'm writing a terminal-mode program in Haskell. How would I go about reading raw keypress information?

In particular, there seems to be something providing line-editing facilities on top of Haskell. If I do `getLine`, I seem to be able to use the up-arrow to get previous lines, edit the text, and only when I press Enter does the text become visible to the Haskell application itself.

What I'm after is the ability to read individual keypresses, so I can implement the line-editing stuff myself.

---

Perhaps my question was unclear. Basically I want to build something like Vi or Emacs (or [Yi](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Yi)). I already know there are terminal bindings that will let me do fancy console-mode printing, so the output side shouldn't be an issue. I'm just looking for a way to get at raw keypress input, so I can do things like (for example) add K to the current line of text when the user presses the letter K, or save the file to disk when the user presses Ctrl+S.

Comment: Maybe the [`readline`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/readline-1.0.3.0) package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you want readline support. There are a couple of packages to do this, but [haskeline](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline) is probably the easiest to use with the most supported platforms.

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import System.Console.Haskeline

type Repl a = InputT IO a

process :: String -> IO ()
process = putStrLn

repl :: Repl ()
repl = do
  minput <- getInputLine "> "
  case minput of
    Nothing -> outputStrLn "Goodbye."
    Just input -> (liftIO $ process input) >> repl

main :: IO ()
main = runInputT defaultSettings repl
```

Comment: Haskeline isn't precisely what I want, but it looks like I may be able to get at what I want by reading the source code...

Comment: I had erroneously assumed the Haskell RTS was doing something strange. However, having written a C program that does raw system calls, I get similar behavior. It seems the terminal itself really is buffering the keypresses, unless you put it into the right mode (which is presumably what `readline` does).

Answer (score 15):

This might be the simplest solution, resembling typical code in other programming languages:

```hs
import System.IO (stdin, hReady)

getKey :: IO [Char]
getKey = reverse <$> getKey' ""
  where getKey' chars = do
          char <- getChar
          more <- hReady stdin
          (if more then getKey' else return) (char:chars)
```

It works by reading more than one character “at a time”. Allowing E.g. the `↑` key, which consists of the three characters `['\ESC','[','A']` to be distinguished from an actual `\ESC` character input.

**Usage example:**

```
import System.IO (stdin, hSetEcho, hSetBuffering, NoBuffering)
import Control.Monad (when)

-- Simple menu controller
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  hSetEcho stdin False
  key <- getKey
  when (key /= "\ESC") $ do
    case key of
      "\ESC[A" -> putStr "↑"
      "\ESC[B" -> putStr "↓"
      "\ESC[C" -> putStr "→"
      "\ESC[D" -> putStr "←"
      "\n"     -> putStr "⎆"
      "\DEL"   -> putStr "⎋"
      _        -> return ()
    main
```

This is a bit hackish, since in theory, a user could input more keys before the program gets to the `hReady`. Which could happen if the terminal allows pasting. But in practice, for *interactive* input, this is not a realistic scenario.

**Fun fact:** The cursor strings can be `putStr`d to actually move the cursor programmatically.

Answer (score 8):

**Incomplete:**

After several hours of web surfing, I can report the following:

- `readline` has a *huge* interface with virtually no documentation whatsoever. From the function names and type signatures you could maybe *guess* what this stuff does... but it's far from trivial. At any rate, this library seems to provide a high-level editing interface - which is the thing I'm trying to implement myself. I need something more low-level.
- After wading through the source of `haskeline`, it seems it has a huge tangle low-level code, seperately for Win32 and POSIX. If there *is* an easy way to do console I/O, this library does not demonstrate it. The code appears to be so tightly integrated and highly specific to `haskeline` that I doubt I can reuse any of it. But perhaps by reading it I can learn enough to write my own?
- Yi is... freaking *massive*. The Cabal file lists > 150 exposed modules. (!!) It appears, though, that underneath it's using a package called `vty`, which is POSIX-only. (I wonder how the hell Yi works on Windows then?) `vty` looks like it might be directly useful to me without further modification. (But again, not on Windows.)
- `unix` has... basically nothing interesting. It has a bunch of stuff to *set* things on a terminal, but absolutely nothing for *reading* from a terminal. (Except maybe to check whether echo is on, etc. Nothing about keypresses.)
- `unix-compat` has absolutely nothing of interest.

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to use [ncurses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ncurses-0.2.11/docs/UI-NCurses.html). A minimalistic example:

```
import Control.Monad
import UI.NCurses

main :: IO ()
main = runCurses $ do
    w <- defaultWindow
    forever $ do
        e <- getEvent w Nothing
        updateWindow w $ do
            moveCursor 0 0
            drawString (show e)
        render
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for [hSetBuffering](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v%3ahSetBuffering). StdIn is line buffered by default, but
you want to receive the keys right away.

Answer (score 4):

I think the [`unix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.1.0) library provides the most lightweight solution for this, especially if you have some familiarity with `termios`, which is mirrored by the `System.Posix.Terminal` module.

There's a good page over at gnu.org that describes using `termios` to set up [non-canonical input mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Noncanonical-Input.html) for a terminal, and you can do this with `System.Posix.Terminal`.

Here's my solution, which transforms a computation in `IO` to use non-canonical mode:

```
{- from unix library -}
import System.Posix.Terminal
import System.Posix.IO (fdRead, stdInput)

{- from base -}
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)
import Control.Exception (finally, catch, IOException)

{- run an application in raw input / non-canonical mode with given
 - VMIN and VTIME settings. for a description of these, see:
 - http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Noncanonical-Input.html
 - as well as `man termios`.
 -}
withRawInput :: Int -> Int -> IO a -> IO a
withRawInput vmin vtime application = do

  {- retrieve current settings -}
  oldTermSettings <- getTerminalAttributes stdInput

  {- modify settings -}
  let newTermSettings = 
        flip withoutMode  EnableEcho   . -- don't echo keystrokes
        flip withoutMode  ProcessInput . -- turn on non-canonical mode
        flip withTime     vtime        . -- wait at most vtime decisecs per read
        flip withMinInput vmin         $ -- wait for >= vmin bytes per read
        oldTermSettings

  {- install new settings -}
  setTerminalAttributes stdInput newTermSettings Immediately

  {- restore old settings no matter what; this prevents the terminal
   - from becoming borked if the application halts with an exception
   -}
  application 
    `finally` setTerminalAttributes stdInput oldTermSettings Immediately

{- sample raw input method -}
tryGetArrow = (do
  (str, bytes) <- fdRead stdInput 3
  case str of
    "\ESC[A" -> putStrLn "\nUp"
    "\ESC[B" -> putStrLn "\nDown"
    "\ESC[C" -> putStrLn "\nRight"
    "\ESC[D" -> putStrLn "\nLeft"
    _        -> return ()
  ) `catch` (
    {- if vmin bytes have not been read by vtime, fdRead will fail
     - with an EOF exception. catch this case and do nothing. 
     - The type signature is necessary to allow other exceptions 
     - to get through.
     -}
    (const $ return ()) :: IOException -> IO ()
  ) 

{- sample application -}
loop = do
  tryGetArrow 
  putStr "." >> hFlush stdout
  loop 

{- run with:
 - VMIN  = 0 (don't wait for a fixed number of bytes)
 - VTIME = 1 (wait for at most 1/10 sec before fdRead returns)
 -}
main = withRawInput 0 1 $ loop
```