# Haskell key input memory leak

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, lazy-evaluation

I came up with the following code for the raw-input problem, as discussed in [SO Haskell read raw keyboard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068218/haskell-read-raw-keyboard-input).  Unfortunately, when I go to ghci, run `getAllInput`, and hit the right arrow key, it never returns.  Unless I kill it pretty quickly, it seems to eat all my memory so that other applications stop responding and I have to restart the OS.  In the Activity Monitor I can see the memory for the ghc process go quickly into the gigabytes.

(1) I think the problem is in the recursive call of `go`, which is evaluated lazily by calling `hReady` before `getChar`; this means `hReady` keeps returning true and the stack grows forever.  Is that plausible?

(2) I'm used to languages in which this would soon cause a stack overflow exception, so it wouldn't prevent me from working.  Is there any general way to protect against this massive memory leak?  Maybe starting ghci with a hard limit on memory use?

```
import System.IO

-- For example, should get "\ESC[C" from the user hitting the right arrow key.
getAllInput :: IO [Char]
getAllInput =
  let
    go :: IO [Char] -> IO [Char]
    go chars = do
      more <- hReady stdin
      if more then go (added chars getChar) else chars
    added :: IO [Char] -> IO Char -> IO [Char]
    added chars char = do
      chars1 <- chars
      char1 <- char
      return (chars1 ++ [char1])
  in do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    firstChar <- getChar
    go (return [firstChar])
```

I'm running ghci 7.10.3 in OS X 10.11.6.  I cleaned up the code in some obvious ways, basically following [the similar SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553473/1480605): putting the `getChar` call in its own line fixes the problem.  But I'd like to understand this better in case it bites me again.

Comment: What does this offer over `getAllInput = liftM2 (:) getChar getAllInput` (or even `getAllInput = getContents`)? The call to `getChar` will already wait until `hReady` is true, so I don't see what waiting for that to be true before calling `getChar` actually buys you.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I'd like the function to terminate after a key press.  I think the SO answer I referred to above explains it pretty well.

Comment: Even after fixing this code, it doesn't terminate after one key press.

Comment: If you start ghci with `ghci getchars.hs  +RTS -M100m` it will give you an error if you do `print $ length [1..]` or the like. This particular program is a peculiar empty loop so it just stays below the requisite level. I'm not sure what could be done about it.

Comment: @DanielWagner This seems to terminate after a key press http://sprunge.us/UEdK Do you have some strange input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion...

(1) As explained by [luqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43164361/2751851), the memory leak is caused by an infinite loop in which lazy evaluation prevents `getChar` from being called.  Adding a line like `c <- getChar` forces the call to happen, so that `go (added chars c)` is now safe to call.

(2) Starting GHCi with a limited heap size, as in `ghci getchars.hs +RTS -M100m`, will interrupt the memory leak before it eats up all memory. See the [GHC Users Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.2/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-flag--M) for further details.

Comment: Note that using `c <- getChar` in this manner implies changing the type of `added`, as suggested by the middle third of luqui's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have an infinite loop in `go`.  If `hReady` returns true, then you call `go` again, which immediately calls `hReady` again, which will of course return true, and so on.   You probably assume that `added` will be run because of `go (added chars getChar)`, but it will not; it is just building an `IO` action and passing it to `go` as an argument, but that argument is only used when `hReady` returns `False`.  The name `chars` is misleading -- `chars` is actually an I/O procedure which will return a list of characters when it is eventually run.

In general, when using monads, a "normal" function signature looks like:

```
:: Foo -> Bar -> Baz -> IO Quuz
```

That is, the monad (`IO`) is only present on the return value, not the arguments.  A signature like

```
:: IO Foo -> IO Bar
```

usually indicates that something higher-order is going on, for example that this function will perhaps execute its argument multiple times or in a new context.

I recommend the signatures

```
go :: [Char] -> IO [Char]
added :: [Char] -> Char -> IO [Char]
```

and trying to get the program to compile from there.

You should also try changing `added` to be a pure function

```
added :: [Char] -> Char -> [Char]
```

because it doesn't actually have any side effects.  The implementation and usage will need to be altered a little, though.

Comment: Thanks, I actually already did all that (that's what I meant by cleaning up the code).  You answered (1) nicely; how about (2)?

Comment: @HewWolff Any program compiled with ghc and `-rtsopts` will accept `+RTS -M1G` (or similar) to set a one gigabyte maximum heap. In particular, ghci will accept this. See `+RTS --help` for more.