# How to read char without echo

Tags: idris

In (*1) we have example how to turn off echo when use getChar in haskell. The idea is we can turn off echo using `hSetEcho stdin False`.

I would like do the same thing in Idris. Do I have a way?

(*1) [Haskell read raw keyboard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068218/haskell-read-raw-keyboard-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the [curses bindings.](https://github.com/JakobBruenker/curses-idris/)

If this is too heavy for your usage, you can write C code that handles this for your terminal, and use that code via FFI interfaces. For example, you can use `termios.h`for Linux terminals like this:

`termops.c`:

```
 #include "termops.h"
 #include <termios.h>

 void set_echo(int fd) {
  struct termios term;
  tcgetattr(0, &term);
  term.c_lflag |= ECHO;
  tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &term);
 }

 void unset_echo(int fd) {
   struct termios term;
   tcgetattr(0, &term);
   term.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
   tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &term);
 }
```

`termops.h`:

```
void set_echo(int fd);
void unset_echo(int fd);
```

`termops.idr`:

```
%include C "termops.h"

setEcho : IO ()
setEcho = foreign FFI_C "set_echo" (Int -> IO ()) 0

unsetEcho : IO ()
unsetEcho = foreign FFI_C "unset_echo" (Int -> IO ()) 0

getPasswd : IO String
getPasswd = do
  c <- getChar
  if c == '\n'
  then pure ""
  else do rek <- getPasswd
          pure $ strCons c rek

main : IO ()
main = do
  unsetEcho
  passwd <- getPasswd
  setEcho
  printLn passwd
```

To compile and link the C library, then use `idris termops.idr --cg-opt "termops.c"`.

Comment: Perfect, as usual. Thank you.